# Istio RequestAuthentication blocks envoy sidecar's Ready status

Tags: istio

Could you please help me in understanding RequestAuthentication?
when I apply simple RequestAuthentication and restart Pod, envoy sidecar's ready state is false, and logs throw `warn    Envoy proxy is NOT ready: config not received from Pilot (is Pilot running?): cds updates: 1 successful, 0 rejected; lds updates: 0 successful, 1 rejected`
as soon I delete RequestAuthentication and recreate pod - works OK
Istio 1.8.3

```
apiVersion: 'security.istio.io/v1beta1'
kind: RequestAuthentication
metadata:
  name: jwt-validator
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: api
  jwtRules:
  - issuer: "https://mykeycloak.com/auth/realms/myrealm"
```

When proxy is in LDS stale state
the following log is shown in istiod

```
2021-04-10T17:30:53.326877Z    warn    ads    ADS:LDS: ACK ERROR sidecar~10.238.2.69~PODNAME.NS~NS.svc.cluster.local-60 Internal:Error adding/updating listener(s) vi ││ rtualInbound: Issuer 'MY_JWT_ISSUER_URL' in jwt_authn config has invalid local jwks: Jwks RSA [n] or [e] field is missing or has a parse error
```

**Resolved**
Issuer here is not just a string to match in JWT, but the real URL that must be accessible from istiod, and with a valid SSL certificate

Comment: Hi @Yegor Lopatin, I see you've solved the issue. Please consider posting that as an answer and accept it, so if someone from the community will have have the same issue he might found the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm placing this answer for better visibility.

---

As @Yegor Lopatin mentioned in edit, the issue was solved by fixing the issuer:

> Issuer here is not just a string to match in JWT, but the real URL that must be accessible from istiod, and with a valid SSL certificate
>
> issuer must be a valid and accessible link. I thought it is just an string, which you compare with when reading JWT

e.g.

```
jwtRules:
  - issuer: "testing@secure.istio.io"
    jwksUri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.5/security/tools/jwt/samples/jwks.json"
```

There are tutorials you might refer to when you're seting up JWT with istio:

- https://www.istiobyexample.dev/jwt
- https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-jwt/